# onmenuitemclick Event is Not Firing in IE6 ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, menu

I had a asp.net Menu control on the master page and binded in the runtime based on the user access rights to the module.  The problem I face is the MenuItemClick event is not fired when I view the website in the Internet Explorer(6.0). But the same is working fine in Firfox.  I tried googling but none of the solutions worked for me.  I was wondring if some one could help me to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with Internet Explorer.

When you used MenuItem you probably used this form:

```
    <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" OnMenuItemClick="NavigationMenu_MenuItemClick" runat="server">
 <items>
  <asp:MenuItem Text="menuItem1" NavigateUrl="Web.aspx" />
  <asp:MenuItem Text="menuItem2" NavigateUrl="otherWeb.aspx" />
 </items>
</asp:Menu>
```

When you wrote in this form, the browser dosen't respect your event, because you gave it the URL to navigate to.
If you want that the browser will respect your event and handle it as well, you should delete the "NavigateUrl" attribute and it will work out.

Comment: Hi,  I'm loading the URLs from the database, then how to remove the NavigateUrl!, what is the solution in such a case?.